# Is it good practice to use try catch only for a part of the code

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net, exception

When I submit the form, I need to validate the input data from an HTML form field, which comes from the user who submitted the data. So inside the `Page_Load` event, I added this.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            AntiForgery.Validate();
        }
        try
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = false;
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["UserDetails"] = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogErrorEvent(ex);
            OutputError(ex);
        }
    }
```

In above code you can see I have added a try-catch code excluding         `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}`. Is this good practice?

This is why I did it: `AntiForgery.Validate();` throws an exception if anti CSRF check fails. When I add `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}` inside try-catch block it throws an exception, but after the exception has been thrown, the application executes this button click code as well. I need to avoid it.

```
    protected void btnSaveUser_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code
    }
```

So I added `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}` code outside the try-catch and working as expected. But I need to know is this good practice?

And the second thing is you can see I have used

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        AntiForgery.Validate();
    }
```

And again I checked

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ViewState["UserDetails"] = null;
}
```

Is this good code? Have any possible way to simplyfy my above code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  I don't think that we have enough of the code to make an educated review of what you are trying to accomplish here.   the button click event needs the validation not the page load

Answer (score 1):

doing `try/catch` like this, will execute the `try/catch` block each time the Page_Load is triggered, which would be unnecessary.

What you need is to validate the user input in `btnSaveUser_Click` event, and when user clicks on `btnSaveUser_Click` the data should go to validation process, 
if there is any error, it should do something about it (e.g. show it to the user to be able to fix it and resubmit it again.).

for the AntiForgery, I would suggest you implement it globally on all `POST` requests. Thus, you'll need to implement a middleware handler which will handle `HttpContext` post requests, and validate the token. This would be a better approach.

For the last question, having both `if(Page.IsPostBack)` and `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` would be redundant.

it should be simplified to :

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // not a postback
}
else
{
    // is a postback
}
```

Comment: So then where should I add try-catch? can I apply it only to else part? because if add inside whole if else statments, My code not working as expected

Comment: @Adam do not do it in Page_Load event. You can do it on `btnSaveUser_Click` event for instance. However, I don't think you'll ever need it for what you said. a simple if statement would be enough to do the job.

Comment: How can I check this code  `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}` inside `btnSaveUser_Click` ?

Comment: I mean can I check this `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}` iinside `btnSaveUser_Click` ? Is it a good thing to do ?

Comment: And one more thing sir, I used `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}` inside `btnSaveUser_Click` and code working as expected. But Do I need to check `if (IsPostBack){}` inside button click? beacuase `btnSaveUser_Click` means it is already POSTback, I'm I correct?

Comment: @Adam, I'm not talking about Anti-Forgery, I'm talking about the `try/catch` block. The `if (IsPostBack){AntiForgery.Validate();}` is not the best approach, you'll go over each page and validate AntiForgery ! this would be a pain in the neck. To resolve it, you'll need to create a `POST` handler on the global `HttpContext` to validate the forgery on each `POST` request. This would be a cross-over protection.

Comment: how can I do it using asp web forms, can you please give me a sample code or tutorial to do it

Comment: @Adam sure, you can use this https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf